# error_log generates no output

Tags: php, trace

In a script I have written:

```
error_log(__FILE__ . ': ' . __LINE__ . "remove trial account at " . date("F j, Y, g:i:s a") . "\n",
        3,
        "/var/tmp/recur-billing.log");
    echo "remove trial account at " . date("F j, Y, g:i:s a") . "<br>";
```

In other words I am sending exactly the same text to both the user invoking the script and the file /var/tmp/recur-billing.log.

When I run the script I see the message displayed to the invoker of the script, but the file /var/tmp/recur-billing.log is not created.  I have run this code on two different systems with the same result.

I am trying to debug a complex problem so I have error_log requests to put information into recur-billing.log all through the code.  None of those entries were being generated so I assumed the script had failed in some invisible manner.  That is why I added the above call to error_log, in a place that I KNEW was executed.

What do I have to do to get php to write the messages?

Other calls to error_log (writing to different file names in /var/tmp) work.  It is just the calls trying to write into recur-billing.log that are not working.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for that log?

Comment: The file does not exist and so does not have any permissions.  The permissions for the directory are obviously OK because other trace files are created.